# Where is the object Action in play.api.mvc?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am a novice of Play Framework. When I learn it on its webpages. I found some code like this:

```
import play.api.mvc._
def logging[A](action: Action[A]) = Action.async(action.parser) { request =>
  logger.info("Calling action")
  action(request)
}
```

I checked its document and there is a function `async` in `ActionBuilder`.

How does `Action.async` works? It seems there is no object `Action` in `play.api.mvc`

Comment: Action accessible from controller. Please, see fore more details: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaActions#Controllers-are-action-generators. Also, please, point do documentation page where you found this code example.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that Action is a function defined like this `  def Action: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent] = controllerComponents.actionBuilder
` which returns a `ActionBuilder` on which you call `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object Action` has been removed in Play 2.8 by [Remove deprecated play.api.mvc.Action #9288](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/9288), and has been replaced by [`BaseController.Action`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/BaseController.html#Action:play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder[play.api.mvc.Request,play.api.mvc.AnyContent]) method which refers to [injected](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Scala-Controller-changes) `controllerComponents.actionBuilder` rather than the global objects

```
  /**
   * ...
   * This is meant to be a replacement for the now-deprecated Action object, and can be used in the same way.
   */
  def Action: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent] = controllerComponents.actionBuilder
```

Notice how, perhaps unconventionally, the method name begins with an uppercase letter. My assumption is this was done to maintain familiar usage

```
def foo(query: String) = Action {
  Ok
}
```