# What is this Scala construct doing?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've been using Play! Framework with Java and would like to try it out with Scala.
I've started on a Scala book but the most basic Play! sample has me completely puzzled:

```
  def index(): Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
```

**What Scala construct is Play! using here?** I understand that we are defining a function that returns an `Action` with a generic parameter `AnyContent`. But the next part has me puzzled. What does the assignment mean in this context?

If I go to definition of Action[AnyContent] it's defined as `trait Action[A] extends EssentialAction { ... }`
If I go to the definition of Action after equals it's defined as:

```
trait BaseController extends BaseControllerHelpers {
  /**
   * The default ActionBuilder. Used to construct an action, for example:
   *
   * {{{
   *   def foo(query: String) = Action {
   *     Ok
   *   }
   * }}}
   *
   * This is meant to be a replacement for the now-deprecated Action object, and can be used in the same way.
   */
  def Action: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent] = controllerComponents.actionBuilder
}
```

Note: I'm interested in the Scala construct that's used I don't care what Play! is actually doing here which I kind of understand.

Comment: It isn't an assignment, `=` here separates method signature from body just like you see in `def Action`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It is not an `object` anymore in recent Play versions, instead it is calling `apply` on the injected `ActionBuilder`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60186550/5205022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially calling `Action.apply()`, which is defined [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L305) in `ActionBuilder`. The first and only parameter of the `apply()` function being the function `request => Ok(...)`.